# GPS is not enabled but isProviderEnabled() is returning true

Tags: android

I can check if GPS is on or not using isProviderEnabled(). If it is not on, I am launching intent so that user can enable GPS. 
At the end I am again checking if GPS is enabled by user or not.
If user does not enable GPS and come out, still isProviderEnabled() is returning NULL.
What could be the issue ? Please guide me.

```
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    // Check if GPS is enabled
    boolean enabled = myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);

    if (!enabled) {
                    // GPS not enabled
        Log.d("", "Provider " + provider + " is not enabled");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
                    // Consider the case when user does not enable GPS and come out. 
    } else {
        Log.d("", "Provider is enabled");

    }       

            // Re-check if user has enabled or not. (Note: case: user has not enabled GPS)
    enabled = myLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);
    if(!enabled)
    {

        Log.d("","provider not enabled");
    }
            else
            {
                    // Control is coming here though user has not enabled GPS in settings
                    Log.d("","GPS is enabled");
            }
```

Thanks,
Biplab

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check GPS enable using this code and let me know what happen,

```
private void CheckEnableGPS(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
      Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
       if(!provider.equals("")){
           //GPS Enabled
        Toast.makeText(AndroidEnableGPS.this, "GPS Enabled: " + provider,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
           startActivity(intent);
       }   
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, It is perfect as I wanted.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I tried it with gps enabled and disabled, and got the same toast both times.

Comment: @BillGary that's probably because your Network or Passive provider is also still active. That provider string should contain ALL the enabled providers, and not just GPS. His check for null only tells us that A provider is enabled, and not which actually is.

Comment: I am kind of scared by that deprecation of Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED in Api 19 but this does work.

Comment: Since KitKat (API 19) you'll need to use `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE` and compare it with 0 (it's an `int` not a string).

Answer (score 8):

I have had this issue on an actual physical device.

I did a few tests using mock locations on my physical Android device, and then switched back to real locations  using the GPS (the code was clean of all mock locations).
A this point, whether the GPS was stopped or not, the application would always return "true" (GPS activated) and for some reason wouldn't register real locations any more.

In this case, rebooting the physical device solved the issue.

Comment: I was getting worried about my app. This helped a great deal. Thanks! 

Also, is there a way to reset mock locations programmatically? I'd like to ensure my app's integrity even for the slightly notorious chunks of my audience.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but for me (back when I tried it) it was the only way I could reset the locations.

Comment: Simply turning location on and off does the job, this is what I'm doing with my App, simply making user to restart his GPS and then using `BroadcastReciever` to make sure user actually restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue where `isProviderEnabled()` would return true on devices < lollipop

Based on user370305's answer I updated my method as follows:

```
private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        return !provider.equals("");

    } else {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean network = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        return gps || network;

    }

}
```